# Is this the correct use of the word jarring?

Tags: vocabulary

"suddenly the jarring reality hit me."

Is this the right use of the word jarring

Comment: More context needed.  Also, what do you understand 'jarring' to mean and why does this usage seem wrong to you?

Comment: Please see "How can I ask about checking my text?" in [Help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details about this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

> "suddenly the jarring reality hit me."

This would be fine if the fact of such a reality has been established, or is going to be established.

> A violent explosion erupted on the right. Suddenly the jarring reality hit me. We were under attack again.

If

> "suddenly the jarring reality hit me."

is an isolated thought, unexplained before or after, then this might be better:

> Suddenly the reality hit me. It was jarring.

Anyway, "jarring" is OK to describe a disturbing sense as it seems to be doing in the example.